# Uploading more than one image using paperclip and active admin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to upload more than one image to products in a app I'm building.
The Images are uploaded via `ActiveAdmin` with `paperclip`

There is no problem uploading one image, but multiple images is not working.

I've tried to use the `jquery-fileupload-rails`gem  and it is supposed to wire into `active admin`, but with out a luck.

I have also searched the web for this and checked out many posts on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a solution yet.

Here is the product model `product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :label

  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy

    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_eur, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true


 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

**THIRD UPDATE**

Ok I added this `images_attributes:` snipped below to the `products_controller.rb` in the end of the `def product_params`

```
def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description,...., images_attributes: [:image , :id , :_destroy])
end
```

And to the `admin/product.rb` I added

```
            f.has_many :images , heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |ff|
            ff.input :image, required: true, as: :file
             end
```

Now I can select images via active admin, but it don't get saved to the database.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Here is the `app/views/pages/index.html.erb`

In that snippet located on the index page the latest upload in each category is shown. See how the app loops through products and shows the corresponding image to each product.  Now I'm getting error from this line `<%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>` in the index file.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
            <div class="row">
              <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>

                    <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                        <% if index == 0 %>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                            <%= link_to category_path (category), { :method => 'GET' } do %>
                                <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
                            <% end %>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p class="category-name" ><%= product.category.name %></p>
                     </div> 
                    <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                    </div> 
                <% end %>
                </div>
            <% end %>

    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
here is the `products_controller.rb`

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
   offset = rand(100)
   @products_rand = Product.where(category_id: 
   @product.category_id).order("RANDOM()").limit(6)
  end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd, :price_eur, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug)
end 
end
```

And this is the Active admin product model `admin/product.rb`

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  config.sort_order = 'position_asc' # assumes you are using 'position' for your acts_as_list column
  config.paginate   = true # optional; drag-and-drop across pages is not supported

  sortable # creates the controller action which handles the sorting

permit_params :title, :slug, :description, :stock_quantity, :image, :price_usd, :price_eur, :category_id, :label_id,  images_attributes: [:image , :id , :_destroy]

    index do
         sortable_handle_column # inserts a drag handle
        column :title
        column :slug
        column :category
        column :label
        column :created_at
        column :stock_quantity

        column :price_eur, :sortable => :price_eur do |product|
            number_to_currency(product.price_eur, :unit => "€ " , :precision => 0) 
        end
        column :price_euro, :sortable => :price_usd do |product|
            number_to_currency(product.price_usd, :unit => "$ " , :precision => 0)
        end

        actions 

    end

    form multipart: true do |f|
            f.inputs "Product Details" do
            f.input :title
            f.input :slug
            f.input :description, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: { toolbar: 'Full' } }
            f.input :stock_quantity
            f.input :image, required: false
            f.input :price_usd
            f.input :price_isl
            f.input :category
            f.input :label
            end
            f.actions   
          end

end
```

And finally here is the product view, `app/views/products/show.html.erb``

```
    <div class="container">  
     <div class="row product_top text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block">
       <div class="product_description">

        <h3 class="title"><%= @product.title %></h3>
        <p class="label-product"><%= @product.label.name %></p>

        <p class="description">Description</p>

        <p class="product-description"><%= @product.description.html_safe %></p>

            <% if @product.stock_quantity <= 0 %>
               <p> Out of stock </p> 
            <% end %>
     </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
         <p class="product-price"> Price:</p> <%= number_to_currency(@product.price_usd, :unit => "€ " , :precision => 0) %> | <%= number_to_currency(@product.price_isl.to_i, :unit => "IKR " , :precision => 0) %>
        </div>

       <%# if @product.stock_quantity >= 1 %>
        <div class="row text-center add-cart-wrapper">  
          <% if @product.stock_quantity >= 1 %>
          <%= link_to 'Add to Cart', product_product_items_path(@product), :method => :post, class: 'add-to-cart'%>
         <% end %>
       </div>
    </div>  
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block" > 
    <%= image_tag @product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive center-block"  %>

  </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="row product-teaser">

  <h4 class="text-center teaser-text"> similar products to <%= @product.title %> : </h4>
   <% @products_rand.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 center-block product-thumbs-product-view" >

  <%= link_to product_path (product) do %>
                <%= image_tag product.image.url, :size => "100%x100%", class: "img-responsive center-block" %>
            <% end %>

          <h5 class="text-center"><%= link_to product.title, product, class: "text-center" %></h5>

      </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That model, as you have it, can only hold one file upload in its `image` attribute. You need to add a `has_many` association to your product so that it can have many files.

i.e. create an Image model that will hold the attachment and be associated to the product:

```
rails g model Image product_id:integer image_file_name:string image_file_size:integer image_content_type:string
rake db:migrate
```

Then associate the product to it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  # ... the rest of your code...
end
```

And move the attached file declaration to your Image model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

Now you have a way of associating many images with one product:

```
product = Product.new
product.images.build image: File.open('some/image/for/example.jpg', ?r)
product.save
product.images.first.image # the Paperclip::Attachment object
```

I can only take you this far since you didn't post any controller, view code, or active_admin setup but, you just need to [read rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) or [active_admin documentation on nested resources](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources) so that you can figure out how to write a nested form that lets you create these images for your Product.

**Update**: If by "taking this answer further" you mean "write the code for you" Then, no. There is enough information here and in the [active_admin documentation on nested resources](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources) for you to figure it out. I can however, provide clarifications if any of this is confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much @DiegoSalazar, I previously accidentally sent an unfinished question :). Now I have added Active admin model, Controller for products, and views.  It would be so nice of you could take your answer further.

Comment: I can't wait to see if @DiegoSalazar will take his answer further since you provided all missing files @DaudiHell.  I've had similar issues with `paperclip´

Comment: I totally understand that you don't want to write this for me, and I wouldn't want that either, I can't see how I would learn from that :)  I've made the `image.rb` model and added the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations to both models. Thing I'm not sure of at the moment is how the product_controller.rb would look since I added all the image logic to a new model, the `image.rb`model.  Do I have to create I new controller for the image.rb model?

Comment: please see ANOTHER UPDATE in the question

Comment: You wouldn't have to change much of your controller except for the strong parameters to allow the new nested fields. And add the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` declaration to your `Product` model. You can read all about that in the [Rails nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) documentation I linked to above.